# SBE files are disappearing on their own from Accpac server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am having some very bizarre, yet serious problem regarding Accpac at a customer’s office.  The issue is that Accpac files + license files (.SBE files) are disappearing on their own from the Accpac server in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage\Sage Accpac` I even installed it in another location. The result is that it displays `You do not have a license to use this product` after the files go missing. We have checked with all users and it seems no one is doing this on purpose. We have tried re-installing Accpac on the server, even re-formatting Windows on the server and re-install Accpac and SQL server but again the files disappear eventually after some time. We have run different antivirus tools but no virus was found. This is very weird for us and very annoying for the customer.

We're using Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Grateful if you could advise on this situation ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect job for [Windows Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). This powerful tool allows you to monitor almost every activity on your system.

While it is powerful it can be also dangerous because when not using proper filters and logging methods it can have a considerable impact on your system (Virtual Memory exhaustion to name one).

In your case I'd do the following:

- download Process Monitor, extract and run it as administrator
- stop the initial capture by pressing `Ctrl+E`
- change the backing file from Virtual Memory to a disk file to lower the possible strain on your system's RAM/Pagefile: `File -> Backing Files... -> Use file named` (a separate disk/partition is best for this)
- apply appropriate filters to your situation: `Filter -> Filter...` select `Event Class is File System` then `Include` and press `Add`
- to narrow the output even further you can specify paths to files you want to monitor: select `Path is <path>` then `Include` and press `Add` and `OK`
- to eliminate all unnecessary events from the capture select `Filter -> Drop Filtered Events`
- start capturing by pressing `Ctrl+E`

This should give you some hints about what exactly is happening to your files while having low impact on your system.

Answer (score 0):

If the file only needs to be read and not updated, set it to readonly and restrict the users from making and changes to it.  Odds are that if one of the stations/users is removing it, the process that does so will bomb out.  mprill's suggestion is a great way to track it down what is actually doing it.